# Performance, Zend Route vs Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-route

How faster is mod_rewrite, compared to Zend Router? Should one give up using Zend Router and do the same things with rewrite rules in apache's virtual host definitions using mod_rewrite?

Is the difference very significant?

I have heard many people saying mod_rewrite has caused some high traffic websites crash, I was wondering if this should be of concern when developing with ZF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're heading towards premature optimisation. Whilst routing only with mod_rewrite might be slightly faster than mod_rewrite + ZF routing, is a 1-2ms speed increase (probably less) really worth the sacrifice in maintainability and flexibility? You should only consider such a course of action if you have an application where you know (through benchmarking) that routing is your bottleneck, and you've already exhausted all of the standard solutions to such a problem.

As for mod_rewrite itself, I've seen it crash sites but only when the rules were badly written (causing it to rewrite the same request multiple times). This isn't really something you need to be concerned about if you're just using ZF's default rule, which simply rewrites all requests to one PHP file.

Comment: I think this comment was more sophisticated, premature optimization is evil.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: just look at the performance between C and Php (LAMP environment).

...

Done?

If I'm not wrong C is usually between 35 and 40 times faster than Php bytecode.

So just imagine that Apache had its own `mod_rewrite`.

`mod_rewrite` is 100% Gnu C (correct me if I'm wrong) and makes calls to the PCRE which is also 100% C.

Knowing that Regexp are pre-compiled, well, errr... may I go further?

No offense, but knowing that, you quickly guess that you'd better try to use RewriteRules. If you think well about it, you can mix RewriteRules and [rewritemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) wisely to get very, **very** fast HTTP server.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1, completly agree. I would just add that sadly it's quite easy to write bad rewrite rules, rewriteMap is a good tool, having an eye at the output of a rewriteLog is also a must (and reading the documentation).

Comment: Thank you Olivier, but I have to slightly disagree, why? It's probably not the case that C is ALWAYS 35 to 40 times faster under any circumstances than PHP, in this context since you must run PHP anyways, the server will have to load PHP and do other things with it anyways, if we were talking about rewriting in a vacuum and nothing else but rewriting then you would probably be correct, but since this is part of a php solution, the difference as someone else has mentioned should be in minimal, at least it doesn't make a huge difference on a development server, I wish we could have numbers here

Comment: nice answer. But anyway, I wish we could have numbers too, because I'm pretty sure that executing RewriteRules, whether Php is loaded or not, will always be faster than Php code. My own results gave me a 35-40% faster (I was analysing `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and acting upon, now I do use tons of RewriteRules to do the same and it's **damn** *way faster*).